# 7-adic series expansion of square root of 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Given the sequence $\{ a_n\}$ defined by the (positive and $a_n < 7^n$) solutions of the congruence $x^2 \equiv 2 \mod 7^n$ and $a_{n+1}\equiv a_n \mod 7^n$. e.g. the first one is $a_1 =3$ the second $a_2 = 3 + 1\cdot 7$, $a_3 = 3 + 1 \cdot 7 + 2 \cdot 7^2$, $a_4 = 3 + 1 \cdot 7 + 2 \cdot 7^2 + 6 \cdot 7^3$, etc...
I would like to prove that the partial sums $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ will converge to a limit $S$ so that $S^2 = 2$ in the $\mathbb{Q}_7$ norm, by elementary methods. I am interested in a direct solution that **does not use advanced methods** or results.

So far I observed that the sequence $\{a_n \}$ does converge to $\sqrt{2}$, and this is what most books also prove, this is direct from the fact $(a_n^2-2)\equiv 0 \mod 7^2 \Rightarrow  |a_n^2 - 2|_7 = \frac{1}{7^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. But I cannot see how this will be extended to the partial sums $S_n$.

Alternatively it seems to me that if I can rearrange the infinite sum $S_{\infty}$ into $a_{\infty}$ then the result follows, but I do not know how to perform such rearrangement, that is how to prove that (even at a formal level only), this is stated in a book but is not proven, nor any hint given:

\begin{eqnarray}
S_{\infty}&=&3 + (3+ 1 \cdot 7) + (3+ 1 \cdot 7 + 2 \cdot 7^2  ) + (3+ 1 \cdot 7 + 2 \cdot 7^2 + 6 \cdot 7^3 ) + \cdots  \\
&=& 3+ 1 \cdot 7 + 2 \cdot 7^2 + 6 \cdot 7^3  + \cdots  = a_{\infty}
\end{eqnarray}

my try was to reduce by $\mod 7$ (and then try reducing by $\mod 7^m$) a given $S_n^2$, I was aiming to get 2 + something with small norm $|\cdot|_7$ and , but this did not work, I could only prove congruence to $2n^2$ which is neither what I expected nor useful.

\begin{eqnarray}
S_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i < j}^n a_i a_j \equiv (2n + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}a_i a_{i+k} ) \mod 7
\end{eqnarray}
then by construction $a_{i+1} \equiv a_i \mod 7$ which implies $a_{i+k} \equiv a_i \mod 7$ hence

$$
S_n^2 \equiv 2n + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}a_i^2 \equiv  2n + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}2 \equiv 2n^2 \mod 7
$$

I think I am on the wrong track here.

Comment: $(a_n)$ is converging to $\sqrt{2}$. Why would you want $(S_n)$ to converge to $\sqrt{2}$ (which is false)?

Comment: This is like trying to prove $1+1.4+1.41+1.414+\cdots$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\Bbb R$. You seem to be confused.

Comment: This statement is written in a book (starting to think, its not a very good one), so I thought it was right. I just started with p-adic numbers so I have not much experience with them. Could you provide a detalied argument on why it is a false statement? No wonder I could not prove it.

Comment: How about give us a verbatim quote of the problem, or cite the exact location of the problem, just in case you're reading it incorrectly?

Comment: Sure, the original is in spanish, but here's my translation, I quote: "Consider the sequence $\{ a_n \}$ with the 7-adic absolute value in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $s_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ for each n \geq 1. Show that the sequence $s_n$ does not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$. In fact if we denote by $\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$ (wherever this limit may live), show that $\alpha$ is a square root of the equation $x^2 =2$, i.e. $\alpha = \sqrt{2}$. This exercise shows that the sequence $\{ s_n \}$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$ in the 7-adic absolute value!"

Comment: After reading the answer below, it is now clear to me that the partial sums cannot converge, the book is simply wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums do not converge. From $a_1\equiv 3\pmod 7$ we see that $a_n\equiv 3\pmod 7$ for all $n$ and hence $S_n$ is periodically $\equiv 3,6,2,5,1,4,0,3,6,2,5,1,4,0,\ldots\pmod 7$ and cannot converge (whatever $S$ you pick, most partial sums would have $|S_n-S|_7\ge 1$).

Remember  that for the convergence of partial sums it is necessary (and in the $p$-adic case also sufficient) that the summdns tend to $0$.

Comment: Thanks, it is now clear to me that the book's exercise is wrong. I was really confused.